# Subgroups of hyperbolic 3-manifold groups

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, low-dimensional-topology

> Let $M$ be a hyperbolic 3-manifold and $\Gamma$ a finitely generated
> subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$. Then either $\Gamma$ is geometrically finite,
> or there exists a finite cover $M'$ of $M$ which fibers over the
> circle, and such that $\Gamma$ is the subgroup of $\pi_1(M')$
> corresponding to the fiber ($\Gamma$ is a *virtual surface fiber
> group*).

I've seen the result above quoted many times. It is said to be a direct consequence of the Tameness Theorem (every hyperbolic 3-manifold with finitely generated fundamental group is topologically tame) and [Canary's Covering Theorem](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82463032.pdf).

I'm having trouble understanding the notion of a geometrically (in)finite end of a 3-manifold (and the definition seems to differ slightly in various places in the literature), and thus I don't understand how Canary's covering theorem leads to the statement above.

I would be very grateful for a rundown of how Canary's theorem implies the subgroup theorem, and also a reference for learning the preliminaries that I need in order to understand Canary's proof.

Comment: What else did you read on the subject besides Canary's paper?

Answer (score 2):

The precise statement you are after requires $M$ to be of finite volume and complete (otherwise, the claim is false). For simplicity of the discussion, I will assume that $M$ is compact. Here are the steps of the proof:

1. The quotient manifold $M'=H^3/\Gamma$ has a "compact core", which is a compact submanifold with boundary $C$, whose inclusion in $M'$ is a homotopy-equivalence. The closures of the complementary components $M'-C$ are called "ends" of $M'$ (by an abuse of terminology). There are finitely many of these.
2. The subgroup $\Gamma$ is geometrically finite if and only if every end is geometrically finite.
3. Every end of $M'$ is topologically tame (which was known as "tameness conjecture"), i.e. is homeomorphic to the product of a surface and an interval.
4. If $E$ is a geometrically infinite (topologically tame) end of $M'$, then either $M$ "virtually fibers" and $\pi_1$ of the fiber is a subgroup commensurable to $\pi_1(M')$, or the restriction of the covering map $p: M'\to M$ to the end $E$ is finite-to-one (this is what Canary proves in the linked paper). In fact, Canary actually proves more, namely, that this restriction is a proper map. (One can also formally prove here that finite-to-one implies proper.) Assume that $p|E$ is proper. Since $M$ is compact and $E$ is not, this is a contradiction.

If you want to read more on this staff, consider reading

*Matsuzaki, Katsuhiko; Taniguchi, Masahiko*, Hyperbolic manifolds and Kleinian groups, Oxford Mathematical Monographs. Oxford: Clarendon Press. ix, 253 p. (1998). [ZBL0892.30035](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0892.30035).

*Ohshika, Ken’ichi*, Discrete groups. Transl. from the Japanese by Ken’ichi Ohshika, Translations of Mathematical Monographs. Iwanami Series in Modern Mathematics. 207. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). x, 193 p. (2002). [ZBL1006.20031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1006.20031).

*Kapovich, Michael*, [**Hyperbolic manifolds and discrete groups**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4913-5), Modern Birkhäuser Classics. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser (ISBN 978-0-8176-4912-8/pbk; 978-0-8176-4913-5/ebook). xxvii, 467 p. (2009). [ZBL1180.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1180.57001).